# Python: Redirect output to several consoles?

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a main program, in which a user can call a sub-process (to download files) several times. Each time, I call aria2c using subprocess, and it will print the progress to stdin. Of course, it is desirable that the user can see the progress of each download seperately.

So the question is how can I redirect the output of each process to a seperate console window?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused. Using subprocess.Popen(...) should spawn a new command prompt automatically for each call. What is aria2c? Is it a program you had written in python as well? Is it a 3rd party exe that writes to the command prompt window?

I can help you to redirect all the sub-processes output to the main command prompt, so it can be displayed inline.

Also, maybe you can give a little more detail on what is going on first, so I can understand your trouble a bit better.

Comment: Aria2c is a third party program. It is weird that only one command prompt is open even though subprocess.Popen is called several time. The exact command I'm using is "Popen(command, shell=True)". And also, will this allow several processes to run at the same time(without waiting for the previous command to finish)?

Comment: When you use the subprocess.Popen you can run multiple processes at the same time. I used this is a Markov Chain simulation, where I ran multiple chains at the same time ( to save time ). Originally my script would open 5 different command prompt windows, and display the output, but I decided it was better to redirect the output to the main window, where I could display each one's progress inline. When the process finished and quit, I would handle it to default output to "Finished". 

  Also, are you running this is linux or windows?

Comment: One more thing, is that the subprocess library can be a little buggy, so you may have to create threaded classes, and spawn new threads to run Aria2c. This might be a lot slower (depending on how aria2c is handled. 

I may suggest creating a submodule in python that just calls the program through os.system(...), and your main script can call a subprocess.Popen() on this submodule with given sys.argv's to use in the system call. 
But if you run this program through python on a single case using just os.system(...) does a window pop up and output is displayed?